# Set caret position to the end for <code> tag

Tags: javascript, input, caret

So, basically I'm making smth like multicolor text area and fill with different colors input data.
For example, user entered words: **one, two, three**.

And I split `<code>` tag value by comma, then wrap all of them and set some color:

```
<code>
<span style="color: green">one</span>,
<span style="color: yellow">two</span>,
<span style="color: red">three</span>
</code>
```

I'm just listening for changes and input newly wrapped words with appropriate colors.
But unfortunately I faced with really strange behavior: after I've inserted this formatted text, caret moved before the last `<span>`. If I'm editing, for example, word **two**, then caret will move to before `<span ...>one</span>`

Does anyone can tell why `<code>` has such strange behavior and how better to make a work-around?...

Comment: Where do you input data? In the code tag? Did you add the `contenteditable` attribute? When do you split by comma? Do you have an event watching the keyboard?

Comment: So, I put `contenteditable` attribute to `<code>` tag and put listener for `'input'` event. When smth changed, I get the whole text of this `<code>` and make a new formatting for that content.
But when I inserted the newly formatted content, caret moves before the `<span>` tag